# Why does disabling --hwvirtex in Vagrant solves problems running a 64-bit OS?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I have set up a Vagrant VM using VirtualBox and the default Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit image from the Vagrant team (see http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box).

When I `vagrant up` on my MacBook Pro using OS X 10.8.5, in 90% of the times I get an error that the VM entered an invalid state (`aborted`). Running the VM with a UI didn't help any further.

Now, while playing around, I found out by random that if I change

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024, "--cpus", 2 ]
end
```

to

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off", "--memory", 1024, "--cpus", 2 ]
end
```

everything is fine. Can anybody explain what setting `--hwvirtex` to `off` does and why this solves my issue?

I'm very confused about this problem as I used a default image from the Vagrant team, and I guess that there are plenty of people who run this image on OS X. So I would have expected to find answers on this when googling, but I didn't.

Any advice?

Using the hint by [che---](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286453/che) and the documentation on [Hardware vs software virtualization](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt), things get worse: I understand what this setting is good for, but not, why it works if I *disable* hardware virtualization.

The documentation states:

> Even though VirtualBox does not always require hardware virtualization, enabling it is *required* in the following scenarios: […] VirtualBox's 64-bit guest support (added with version 2.0) and multiprocessing (SMP, added with version 3.0) both require hardware virtualization to be enabled.

As OS X is 64-bit, and the guest is as well - why does it work at all if I disable hardware virtualization?

*This question is not programming-related, but it is related to a tool which is commonly used by programmers. The FAQ states clearly that questions like these are welcome, hence I posted it here.*

Comment: How did you enable multiple CPUs with `hwvirtex` disabled?

Answer (score 4):

Ola Golo,

just see your tweet about this question ;-)

It's very simple. The vboxmanage documentation [says](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html):

> --hwvirtex on|off: This enables or disables the use of hardware virtualization extensions (Intel VT-x or AMD-V) in the processor of your host system;

This has nothing to do with vagrant but with VirtualBox. Did you have any problems with VirtualBox? 
I'm running 10.8.5, too, but w/o any problems, using heavy vagrant and vb for my continuous delivery scenarios or puppet coding. I'm using most of the time Ubuntu 12.04 64, too. Sometimes 32b.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fast response :-). Just for the sake of completeness, the docs for `hwvirtex` are at http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt … regarding your question: No, I did not have any problems using VirtualBox stand-alone, hence I *assumed* that it may be a Vagrant problem. How could I track down the issue?